# Docker does not seem to be passing command to entrypoint

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've got the following in my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT echo "wtf"
CMD ["wtf wtf"]
```

When I start it up I get:

```
nginx_1      | wtf
```

I would expect the output to be `wtf wtf wtf` instead of `wtf`.

---

Modifying the Dockerfile to:

```
ENTRYPOINT echo "$@"
CMD ["wtf wtf"]
```

Results in empty out

---

Why aren't the additional commands passed to echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the array representation in the entrypoint as well as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) it is the preferred way of specifying ENTRYPOINT:

> ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"] (exec form, preferred)

If it's not in array form docker won't understand which part is the command and what are the arguments.